# c: How to write c program to detect and identify tokens from reading a file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read tokens from a file and want to show them in the terminal. I'm doing this multiple steps, I've created a c program that can detect tokens. But it's harder for me to read tokens from a text file and show it to the terminal that which is operator, integer, keywords, or identifier. Can anyone help me to do it please?

**Here is the identifier.c file:**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Returns 'true' if the character is a DELIMITER.
bool isDelimiter(char ch)
{
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' ||
        ch == '/' || ch == ',' || ch == ';' || ch == '>' ||
        ch == '<' || ch == '=' || ch == '(' || ch == ')' ||
        ch == '[' || ch == ']' || ch == '{' || ch == '}')
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the character is an OPERATOR.
bool isOperator(char ch)
{
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' ||
        ch == '/' || ch == '>' || ch == '<' ||
        ch == '=')
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is a VALID IDENTIFIER.
bool validIdentifier(char* str)
{
    if (str[0] == '0' || str[0] == '1' || str[0] == '2' ||
        str[0] == '3' || str[0] == '4' || str[0] == '5' ||
        str[0] == '6' || str[0] == '7' || str[0] == '8' ||
        str[0] == '9' || isDelimiter(str[0]) == true)
        return (false);
    return (true);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is a KEYWORD.
bool isKeyword(char* str)
{
    if (!strcmp(str, "if") || !strcmp(str, "else") ||
        !strcmp(str, "while") || !strcmp(str, "do") ||
        !strcmp(str, "break") ||
        !strcmp(str, "continue") || !strcmp(str, "int")
        || !strcmp(str, "double") || !strcmp(str, "float")
        || !strcmp(str, "return") || !strcmp(str, "char")
        || !strcmp(str, "case") || !strcmp(str, "char")
        || !strcmp(str, "sizeof") || !strcmp(str, "long")
        || !strcmp(str, "short") || !strcmp(str, "typedef")
        || !strcmp(str, "switch") || !strcmp(str, "unsigned")
        || !strcmp(str, "void") || !strcmp(str, "static")
        || !strcmp(str, "struct") || !strcmp(str, "goto"))
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is an INTEGER.
bool isInteger(char* str)
{
    int i, len = strlen(str);

    if (len == 0)
        return (false);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1' && str[i] != '2'
            && str[i] != '3' && str[i] != '4' && str[i] != '5'
            && str[i] != '6' && str[i] != '7' && str[i] != '8'
            && str[i] != '9' || (str[i] == '-' && i > 0))
            return (false);
    }
    return (true);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is a REAL NUMBER.
bool isRealNumber(char* str)
{
    int i, len = strlen(str);
    bool hasDecimal = false;

    if (len == 0)
        return (false);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1' && str[i] != '2'
            && str[i] != '3' && str[i] != '4' && str[i] != '5'
            && str[i] != '6' && str[i] != '7' && str[i] != '8'
            && str[i] != '9' && str[i] != '.' ||
            (str[i] == '-' && i > 0))
            return (false);
        if (str[i] == '.')
            hasDecimal = true;
    }
    return (hasDecimal);
}

// Extracts the SUBSTRING.
char* subString(char* str, int left, int right)
{
    int i;
    char* subStr = (char*)malloc(
            sizeof(char) * (right - left + 2));

    for (i = left; i <= right; i++)
        subStr[i - left] = str[i];
    subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
    return (subStr);
}

// Parsing the input STRING.
void parse(char* str)
{
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    while (right <= len && left <= right) {
        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == false)
            right++;

        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left == right) {
            if (isOperator(str[right]) == true)
                printf("'%c' IS AN OPERATOR\n", str[right]);

            right++;
            left = right;
        } else if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left != right
                   || (right == len && left != right)) {
            char* subStr = subString(str, left, right - 1);

            if (isKeyword(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS A KEYWORD\n", subStr);

            else if (isInteger(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS AN INTEGER\n", subStr);

            else if (isRealNumber(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS A REAL NUMBER\n", subStr);

            else if (validIdentifier(subStr) == true
                     && isDelimiter(str[right - 1]) == false)
                printf("'%s' IS A VALID IDENTIFIER\n", subStr);

            else if (validIdentifier(subStr) == false
                     && isDelimiter(str[right - 1]) == false)
                printf("'%s' IS NOT A VALID IDENTIFIER\n", subStr);
            left = right;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// DRIVER FUNCTION
int main()
{
    // maximum legth of string is 100 here
    char str[100] = "int a = b + 1c; ";

    parse(str); // calling the parse function

    return (0);
}
```

**Here is the token.txt file that I need to read from and show it to the terminal:**

```
1) Keywords: 
for, while, if 

2) Identifier
total, sum, average, a, b, c

3) Operators:
 '+', '++', '-' etc.

4) Separators:
', ' ';' etc

5) Integers:
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: At first please don't spam tags. C and C++ are different languages, so please only use one of. Your question doesn't seem to refer to one specific version of C++, so don't use these version tags either.

Comment: @Aconcagua I've deleted it

Comment: Off topic: Don't place parentheses around return values; `return` is not a function. There even is a rarely used feature by which you produce references that way in C++ (`decltype(auto)` return type), and if these are to local variables, they are dangling. And please don't have `if(condition) return true; return false;`, just write`return condition;`.

Comment: @Aconcagua ok i will do it. But how can I read from file and check it

Comment: I personally wouldn't bother to write this code, and use a lexical analyser generator, like Flex (and a parser generator like Bison).

Comment: @Cheatah can You write the code, please. It will be so helpful

Comment: Your `isIdentifier` is not strict enough if you want to check C or C++ (or yet some other languages). It would allow to include e. g. `#` in the name or it would allow names starting with `__` or with `_` + capital letter, which are both reserved for the implementation (i. e. for use of the compiler).

Comment: `|| (str[i] == '-' && i > 0)` – you are checking with *every* iteration, that's inefficient (though if you are lucky, compiler optimises that away, but don't rely on). Better check only once before the loop; a very compact form might look like this: `for(i = str[0] == '-'; i < len; ++i)` – the comparison results in either 0 or 1, so you'd skip first character if it equals to `-` and starts there otherwise.

Comment: You iterate over the string twice, once for finding the length, once for your tests. Actually you can use the same stop condition as `strlen` does and skip the first iteration: You stop as soon as you find `str[someIndex] == 0`...

Comment: Your `isRealNumber` allows for numbers like `10.12.7`.

Comment: Your way of comparing booleans is condidered bad style by many, instead of `condition == true` or `condition == false` you should rather prefer just having the condition or negate it with `!` respectively (`if(condition)` or `if(!condition)`).

Comment: @Aconcagua I will edit that later. But now I've solve how to read from the file

Comment: The tokens file you present does not match a source code file your (incomplete) parser might match against. Are you sure you are on the right way? Could your task rather be to create a list of valid tokens?

Comment: @Aconcagua How can i write that. Can you write full code?

Comment: @Aconcagua First time it was just like detect the token. but now,  it should be read from a file. I know there are mistakes but it works fine. And I will solve it later. But now I have to complete the code. How can I do that?

Comment: @Aconcagua is there any needed to edit the token.txt file?

Comment: Well, SO is *not* a code writing service, you are expected to write the code on your own and ask for help to specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Is the tokens.txt file written by you or have you received it as part of the task? If you've written it as input for your parser, then it should instead contain some code in the language you try to parse.

Comment: @Aconcagua It was written by me. But there was some instruction that there should operator, integer, identifiers and etc. it must be in token.txt file. And I've to detected it and show it in the terminal

Comment: By the way, don't you need functions definitions and calls?

Comment: @Aconcagua where? In token.txt file?

Comment: Well, containing operators, integers identifiers does most likely not mean to list them, but to write code that contains at least one instance of each. So `10 + 12` would be a valid expression in your language, but does not contain keywords or identifiers so far, but only integers and an operator.

Comment: Function definitions and calls in your parser. You currently cannot detect `void f(void) { /* some code */ }` or calling such functions later on `int a = g(7);` – and you haven't considered comments either.

Comment: @Aconcagua I've done it in that way. And the toke.txt file was int a = b + 1c;. But the teacher said there should be  keywords like: for, while and  Integers:
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 like what I've checked in the program. But I've no idea how to do that

Comment: Well, you'd write some C-like code then (not true C, as there are no functions contained, rather a separate script language similar to python that allows free-standing code) containing some more expressions. Think about anything you could do with your variables. By the way: `1c` shouldn't be a valid identifier even with in this language. Imagine up something like this: `int a = b + c; while(a > 0) { a--; } c += b; for(a = 0; a < c; ++c) { b = b + a; }`

Comment: Do you need to consider variables having been declared before you use them? My example above isn't valid as some C-style script as only `a` is declared, `b` and `c` don't exist yet. To make it C-style-valid, you'd need to enforce `int b = 10, c = 12;` or something alike being prepended to my example above.

Comment: Would you have to detect complete *expressions*, each of separated by a semicolon?

Comment: @Aconcagua I think to detect complete expression, each of separate by a semicolon will be great.  is it possible to detect what I've declared in the token.txt file?

Comment: @Aconcagua Neither I've to detect it by each of separated by semicolon

Comment: OK. I've added an answer for the file reading part. But you should seriously consider the errors in your parser. Yet another issue there: `if(condition) {} else if(complement) {}` is just an obsolete if-check. If the condition is not met, then the complement *must* be. So you should just have `if(condition) {} else {}`.

Comment: Your parser cannot detect `++` operator!

Comment: Your delimiter list doesn't contain `\n`,`\r` and `\t` characters!

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions @Aconcagua? I am surprised it wasn't mentioned before.

Comment: @JohnSimoes They might allow more compact code and more efficient scanning – but in the end one needs to specify the same conditions as the functions now do, too. Would they really help understanding the very basics?

Answer (score 0):

File IO in C can be done in two ways, buffered and unbuffered. Buffered IO wraps around the `FILE` type and the `f...` functions like `fopen`, `fread`, `fscanf`, `fclose` and so on.

Unbuffered IO is done via `open`, `read`, `write` and `close` functions.

Typically you'd rather rely on the buffered variant, so showing about that one:

```
FILE* in = fopen(path_to_file, "r");
//                              ^ open file for reading

if(!in)
{
    // opening file was not successful
    // TODO: appropriate error handling like printing an error message
}
else
{
    char buffer[128];
    size_t num;
    while((num = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sizeof(*buffer), in)) > 0)
    {
        // use buffer up to buffer[num]
    }

    // if you are interested if an error occurred or just the end of file
    //  has been read, you can now check e. g. via
    if(!feof(in))
    {
        // error handling
    }

    fclose(in);
}
```

More complex file handling might include moving partially read tokens at the end of the buffer towards its front and filling the buffer from there on:

```
char buffer[128];
size_t offset = 0, num;
while((num = fread(buffer + offset, sizeof(buffer) - offset, sizeof(*buffer), in)) > 0)
{
    // you discover e. g. n non-delimiter bytes at the end possibly not being
    // a complete token at position pos

    memmove(buffer, buffer + pos, n);
    offset = n;
}
```

Comment: should I need to include all the logic to while loop?

Comment: Yes. You'd read one line from the file, detect all tokens and then continue with next part of the file. My variant doesn't consider line endings (if you have long lines you might end up there anyway even with `fgets`), so you need to be aware that a token might be split up between two reads. So if a code segment doesn't stop with a separator character keep that started token and append next code segment afterwards,just as shown in second loop.

Comment: can you just edit and write full code please?

Comment: @TusarHaque SO is *not* a code writing service. You will get the hints you need to complete the code on your own, but that's left to you then. You should be glad about, otherwise you wouldn't be learning anything ;) So try and do your best effort, and if you get stuck again, you can ask a new question. Keep a better eye on creating an [mre] next time, please.

Comment: Okay. Thanks.. I will try my best